# Pass ajax data to another function

Tags: javascript

I want to apply the `getStatus` function right here:

```
function getStatus(id)
{
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: '<?php echo base_url('marketplace/get_store_status'); ?>/'+id,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            return data.status;
        }
    });
}
```

Into this function right here:

```
$('#store-status').click(function() {
    var id = getStatus(<?php echo $vendor->store_id; ?>);
    if (id == 1) {
    $('#btn-status')
        .removeClass('btn-danger')
        .addClass('btn-primary')
        .text('Activate');
    } else {
        $('#btn-status')
        .removeClass('btn-primary')
        .addClass('btn-danger')
        .text('Deactivate');
    }
    console.log(id);
    $('#modal-status').modal('show');
});
```

But when i log the `id` variable in the element click function into the console, it shows `undefined`.

But when i log the success data from the getStatus function itself, it shows the correct data. What am I doing wrong in my code?

Comment: What value is returned in `<?php echo $vendor->store_id; ?>` ?

Comment: ever heard of callback

Comment: The getStatus in Ajax stands for asynchronous. That means sending the request (or rather receiving the response) is taken out of the normal execution flow. In your example, $.ajax returns immediately and the next statement, return result;, is executed before the function you passed as success callback was even called. 

**Possible solutions**

There are basically two ways how to solve this:

Make the AJAX call synchronous (lets call it SJAX).
Restructure your code to work properly with callbacks.

Comment: Then why are people downvoting my answer? lel

Comment: @EdwardBlack the value returned from `<?php echo $vendor->store_id; ?>` is a number

Comment: Did you checked if it is really returned?

Comment: @EdwardBlack yes it did, otherwise there would be a PHP error on my page, and my javascript codes wouldn't parse correctly because it returned with error.

Comment: @padejar where exactly do you check if `id` does even contain a value? I see no checks at all in your code, so how can you be sure that no empty value is returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ajax call is asynchronous. You need to pass a callback instead.

You could make it synchronous too, but that delays your page and can cause issues if the call takes longer

```
function getStatus(id, callback)
{
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: '<?php echo base_url('marketplace/get_store_status'); ?>/'+id,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            callback && callback(data.status);
        }
    });
}


$('#store-status').click(function() {
    var id = getStatus(<?php echo $vendor->store_id; ?>, function(id), {
   // the code here
});

});
```

Comment: What is the && doing? Why is it needed?

Comment: it is an if statement. `callback &&` checks if callback exists, and if so, do `callback(data.status)`. If not, ignore it. It prevents calling functions that don't exists and causing errors. It is a sanity check ;)

Comment: Nice, good to know :)

Comment: Thanks will try it right now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your code after `var id = getStatus(<?php echo $vendor->store_id; ?>);` runs without waiting for a response, because you make an asynchronous call.
One solution is to set `async` to `false` to make the call synchronous, which is not recommended though.

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    async: false,
    url: '<?php echo base_url('marketplace/get_store_status'); ?>/'+id,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        return data.status;
    }
});
```

Another better solution would be to use a callback function.

Comment: yep much better than other one cause the existing code wont need to be restructured.

Comment: No actually it is up to 20 times slower this way, always use callback functions like @Rene Pot showed in his answer. But it is a alternative.

Comment: Out of the ~5 different solutions to this problem, `async: false` is the easiest and worst possible way. **This will freeze the tab until the HTTP call returns, which could take a few seconds**

Comment: But it is a working solution, so no need to downvote.